# Interaction of 2 lines

Tags: calculus

> Show that the following lines intersect
>
> $L_{1}:x=2+t,y=2+3t,z=3+t$, $L_{2}:x=2+t,y=3+4t,z=4+2y$

$L_{1}:(2,2,3)+t(1,3,1)$

$L_{2}:(2,3,4)+t(1,4,2)$

$(1,3,1)$ and $(1,4,2)$ are not proportional (are linear independent) and therefore the intersect

Is the way is correct? can I use the direction vectors?

Comment: For what values of $t$ do they intersect? You haven't answered the question.

Comment: @ziggurism I know, I did not need to give the point of intersection, I just had  to prove that the intersect.
If they are not parallel so they must intersect somewhere

Comment: Well you have not proved it. Lines which are not collinear need not intersect. They are called skew lines.

Comment: You need to use a different parameter rather than the same $t$ for each line. Solve them simultaneously to see if they are consistent.

Comment: Um, but skew lines...

Comment: @gbox in general you should prove a thing happens by explicitly stating the numbers which make it happen. So actually the problem does ask you to give the point of intersection. There are problems susceptible to less constructive proofs, but this isn't one of them. And in general that shouldn't be your attitude.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for two lines to have nonproportional direction vectors and still not intersect.  See [skew lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines).

To show that they intersect, you'll need to show that there is some $t$ and some $s$ such that $$(2,2,3)+t(1,3,1) = (2,3,4)+s(1,4,2)$$

Answer (score 0):

No, this argument works in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but not in $\mathbb{R}^3$, where lines may be nonparallel and still do not intersect (for example if they lay in parallel planes). You have to find out if the equation 
$$
(2,2,3)+t(1,3,1)=(2,3,4)+s(1,4,2)
$$
is solvable.